# Rapid drops in free memory on RDS MySQL Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Recently, we've been having problems with our db.t3.xlarge RDS Instance running MySQL 8.0.28. We have a large number of cronned python scripts that run a high volume of read and write queries against the database. All of our tables use the InnoDB Storage Engine.

The past few months, we've encountered periods of the database becoming completely unresponsive for a few minutes. These situation occur 2-3 times per week at irregular intervals, and during that time, users are unable to run any queries against the database. Recently, we noticed that these slowdowns have coincided with rapid drops in Free Memory in the RDS Monitoring tools:

[image: Free Memory in MB Over the Past Week]

We've had difficulty identifying the cause of these memory drops, as re-executing queries under different scenarios does not cause the same slowdowns. Has anyone every seen these aggressive drops in memory, and have tips for what kinds of query activity could be causing it?

Comment: Does one cron task ever fail to finish before the next invocation starts?

Comment: @RickJames There could be any number of jobs running simultaneously.

Comment: I'm thinking of a cron task that runs, say, every hour.  But sometimes that task takes more than an hour.  If there is no interlock on the task, now you have two copies of the same task stumbling over each other.